# Force all network traffic go through default gateway

Tags: centos, networking, route

I have a machine that I want to force all traffic to go through the default gateway.
Even traffic on the local network.

I have made it to work by removing the auto generated route for this interface, but is it a way to do it permanently in RHEL/Centos by the network scripts?

Default routing table used to look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

But I want it to be after a network restart:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Put every machine on its own /30 ? You can get a million /30's in 10.x.y.z.

Answer (score 2):

At least the route to the gateway need to be direct, i.e. you need

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask           Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0           UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The best way is to modify the netmask of your local network (from `/24 = 255.255.255.0` to 
`/32 = 255.255.255.0` and set the network address to "192.168.1.1". Then all traffic should go through the gateway.

Comment: If you assign a /32 on the local interface, the default gateway will be outside the network, and the most systems does not like that.

Comment: @toed That depends which is the network address. If it is 192.168.1.0, its definitely outside the network, but you can also choose 192.168.1.1 as network adress. I will clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no method to remove the route that I want by the network-scripts.
I guess it is not a very common use-case, but I really don't want servers on the same network being able to talk to each other.

But I did found one script that runs after the network is initialized.

The script `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-post` calles `/sbin/ifup-local` at the end, if it exists.

So I did create that one with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip route delete 192.168.1.0/24
```

After a network restart, I did not have this local network route.

Comment: You can also add this `ip` statement to the `up` hook on your interface config file to delete this route after the interface comes up. Another handy way to statically route traffic.

Answer (score 0):

To make your changes stick in rhel/centos, create the file `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes` with a line beginning with the keyword `any` followed by the arguments you gave to `route add`.

In the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface>` replace or add a line `DEFROUTE="no"`.